# The order of acquireWriteLock of two node when change the relationship using neo4j

Tags: neo4j

It is said when change a relationship, its correlated nodes will be writelocked. I want to know which node will be locked first. This requirement occurs because I need to lock the two nodes manually sometimes and I'm afraid it will cause deadlock if lock them in a different order. Should I worry about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j locks the node with the lowest id, then if it isn't a self-relationship, the node with the highest id. This is so since at least 2.2(.latest).

Answer (score 2):

To be clear:

- A relationship's start and end nodes are only automatically write-locked during relationship **creation** or **deletion**.

  - The end node with the lower native ID is locked first.

    - Before [Issue 6914](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6914) was fixed, relationship *deletion* actually locked the end nodes in a different way -- the start node was always locked first. The latest versions of 2.2, 2.3, as well as 3.x no longer have this inconsistency.
  - During relationship deletion, the relationship itself is also write-locked -- after its end nodes have been locked.
- If you are just adding/removing/deleting a relationship's properties, only the relationship is write-locked. The end nodes are *not* locked.